# Como seria possível realizar busca em combobox C#

Tags: c#

Não consegui fazer o combobox habilitar para digitar a pesquisa
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: qual componente está usando?

Comment: Windows form Application

Comment: Estou fazendo a quebra de linha na query sql utilizando char(10), quando utilizo o combobox padrão já não formata com a quebra de linha somente o metroCombobox, so que ele não habilita para digitar uma pesquisa

Comment: se baixa esse pacote aonde?

Comment: gerenciador NuGet

Comment: o metro não tem o recurso que você precisa.

Comment: Mais teria como fazer isso no c#,
como da imagem a cima?,
como os dados que esta:
 PIPOCA(PIPOCA POLENTA MAMAO)

Comment: ?Como esse componente não, talvez outro mas, esse não... tem que procurar

Answer (score 0):

Opa, pelo que entendi você está querendo um AutoComplete é isso?

Um textbox que reage ao evento de digitação do usuário mostrando as opções que combinam com o texto digitado?

Se fosse, tem esse exemplo da documentação do Windows Forms onde sugerem utilizar a propriedade AutoCompleteMode do componente TextBox.

[AutoComplete no Windows Forms (exemplo)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletemode?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Resolvi amigo com o MultiColumnComboBox EWSoftware, obg!